# Declare a string variable that can hold string larger that 1024 chars in vb6

Tags: string, vb6

I need to declare a string to hold text larger than 1024 characters. In my application srting variables can hold maximum 255 chars. What should I do?

Answer (score 9):

Where did you get this idea?  The maximum string length in VB6 is over a billion characters.

See here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?395267-maximum-length-for-string-in-VB6

Comment: Good heavens. What I said applies to VB6 as well. In addition why aren't you using VB.NET, it's free.

Comment: @KrishanuDey It is similar in VB6 see this [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?395267-maximum-length-for-string-in-VB6). Maybe if show some code we might have a better idea what is going on

Comment: Ah Mark Hall. I'm pretty sure we've worked on a few problems together on here before. Good to see you again.

Comment: If 2 billions can be stored then why my application is exiting whenever the string reaches 255 long?

Comment: As Mark asked, please post the code and we will try and help you.

Comment: @KrishanuDey If your program is exiting, that implies you are having an error, what error code are you getting ?

Comment: @KrishanuDey also in VB6 you can declare fixed length strings. If you have any declarations like this `Dim Name As String * 255` then that would limit your string length to 255 characters

Comment: See as this is the correct ansswer, kindly mark it as such!  Thanks.

Comment: @BobRodes: Actually Bob, he was right, I edited the answer in response to his comment, but either way the answer is the same.